Is $push+$reduce really slower than a custom accumulator?
Let's say I have a few million documents in a MongoDB collection that look like this:
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "schema": "1.0.0",
    "value": 3,
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2024-01-01T01:00:00Z",
    "schema": "1.2.0",
    "value": -10,
  },
  ...
]

Now, I want to do the following, using an aggregation pipeline:

Group documents by day (this is no problem and can be solved like here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/group-by-time-interval-and-offset-interval/202949)
Within each bucket, find the absolute maximum for value (keeping the original sign), plus adding the original document's timestamp and schema.

So, the desired output is something like:
[
    // January bucket
  {
    "bucket": "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "value": {
      "timestamp": "2024-01-01T01:00:00Z",
      "schema": "1.2.0",
      "absMax": -10
    }
  }
]

Obviously, the default $max accumulator does not work, as it has two problems:

It can not keep the original sign when querying absolute maxes
It does not include timestamp and schema, but only outputs the numeric value

So, I tackled the problem trying two different ways:

In my $group stage, I use $push to push all raw documents into a $raw document, which I then go through with $reduce. I need the $raw document to have timestamp and schema always available.
In my $group stage, I use a custom accumulator function (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/) that reduces each document and keeps the original timestamp and schema next to the absolute maximum in its state.

Now, I encounter the following issues:

Solution 1 runs into memory issues, as pushing millions of documents into RAM exceeds MongoDB's hard limit of 100MB of RAM per aggregation step
Solution 2 does look quite ugly in code and MongoDB advises against using custom accumulator functions written in JavaScript.

I updated my question with MongoDB playgrounds:

Solution 1 ($push): https://mongoplayground.net/p/01e5Oa58VfV
Solution 2 (custom accumulator): https://mongoplayground.net/p/M5mUNR7jKgP

And for the sake of completeness using only $min and $max, but losing timestamp and schema: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UegNExWo2np
Solution 2 is about twice as fast as solution 1 on big data sets.
Am I overlooking something?

Please show us your code. Otherwise it is difficult to understand your two solutions.

If the output format is not a hard requirement, you may consider using $setWindowFields

You can group easier with $dateTrunc. For min and max value you can use $bottom or $first
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { absValue: { $abs: "$value" } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$timestamp",
          unit: "month",
          timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
        }
      },
      maxValue: {
        $bottom: {
          sortBy: { absValue: 1 },
          output: {
            timestamp: "$timestamp",
            schema: "$schema",
            value: "$value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

For the minValue use either $top or change the sort order to sortBy: { absValue: -1 }
If you like to use $first and $last then you need to sort the entire collection, i.e.
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { absValue: { $abs: "$value" } } },
  { $sort: { absValue: 1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$timestamp",
          unit: "month",
          timezone: "Europe/Zurich"
        }
      },
      value: {
        $last: {
          timestamp: "$timestamp",
          schema: "$schema",
          value: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

But I think this will be slower.
The rest is just some cosmetic.

Thanks, this helps! Still, when aggregating more than one value (let's say I have 10 different value fields like value1, value2, etc.) in my group, the objects I need to push into RAM exceed the memory limit.
I also tried to cut larger queries into chunks that are executed in parallel on my cluster - still the 100MB limit seems to be the bottleneck here.

For sure $reduce will be slower. I don't know why your first solution exceed 100MiByte but your second not. Maybe it uses only 99 MiByte which means, it works for the moment but not future proof. BTW, you can use $max an $min directly on an array, i.e. $reduce is not required, for example { $project: { value: { $max: "$raw.values.value" } } }

Please see my update.

Thank you for your efforts, I found using $sort to be faster than $reduce following your solution. In my case, the custom accumulator is a bit faster, which is funny as MongoDB strongly advises against it. Maybe it is a trade-off between performance and maintainability. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Yes, I also have a case where $function is significantly faster (and much shorter) than mongo native functions. Be aware, in MongoDB version 8.0 server-side JavaScript functions ($accumulator, $function, $where) are deprecated.

Yeah, I saw your post in the MongoDB forum (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-is-function-deprecated-in-mongod-8-0/291213). We will transition away from server-side JS as fast as possible, even though this may cost us performance. Thanks again.
